# didAddAnnotationViews not getting called always

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I added a MKAnnotation delegate handler class into a MKMapView like this.

```
MapAnnotation *anAnnotation = [[[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord] autorelease];
[myMapView addAnnotation:anAnnotation];
```

The MapAnnotation implements the MKAnnotation.

However didAddAnnotationViews doesnt get called always. Sometimes (rarely) it does and sometimes its not. I checked few places and I have used this correctly. Does it depends on span attributes as well?

MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=0.005f;
    span.longitudeDelta=0.005f;

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

location.latitude = searchLocation.coordinate.latitude;
location.longitude = searchLocation.coordinate.longitude;

region.span=span;
region.center=location;

[myMapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[myMapView regionThatFits:region];
```

Whats wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This delegate method is called for annotations that are currently visible i.e. those that are within the map region that is currently displayed on the screen.

Comment: This seems to be the case, but I cant't seem to find it in the documentation where it only says "Tells the delegate that one or more annotation views were added to the map".

Comment: @Vanja this is correct because annotation view are only added when the coordinate is in visible map region.